# Multiple instances of a component parsed are being parsed as one

Tags: vue.js

Consider this:

```
<div id="app">
  <test-component to="abc">Some ABC</test-component>
  <test-component to="xyz">Some XYZ</test-component>
  <test-component to="123">Some 123</test-component>
</div>

----

Vue.component('test-component', {
  template: '<a :href="to"> <slot></slot> </a>',
  props: ['to'],
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

All three "test-components" are rendered as expected. See https://jsfiddle.net/gotp1fdL/1/

However, when I implement a wrapper App component, only the first "test-component" is rendered and the others are even disregarded... 
See https://jsfiddle.net/gsxq9ajc/

```
<div id="app">
  <app></app>
</div>

<template id="application">
  <test-component to="abc">Some ABC</test-component>
  <test-component to="xyz">Some XYZ</test-component>
  <test-component to="123">Some 123</test-component>
</template>

---

Vue.component('test-component', {
    template: '<a :href="to"> <slot></slot> </a>',
    props: ['to'],
});

Vue.component('app', {
    template: '#application',
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

Please could someone explain why? What is missing to have all components rendered isolated, without issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following, as shown in the console:

> vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>
> Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are
>   using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Adding a wrapper in you app component will fix it.

```
<template id="application">
  <div>
    <test-component to="abc">Some ABC</test-component>
    <test-component to="xyz">Some XYZ</test-component>
    <test-component to="123">Some 123</test-component>
  </div>
</template>
```